# How do I extract multiple files at once?

Tags: find, bash-scripting, rar

I have a number of rar files stored like so:

```
/torrents/televisionshowS01E0$X/nameoftelevisionshow.rar
```

where $X is a variable ={0,1,2,...,12}

I would like to extract them using a single command to a single output directory (`/publicshare/`).

Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in find /torrents/televisionshowS01*/ -name *.rar; do unrar x "$i" /publicshare/;done
```

but I'm getting the following result:

```
Cannot open /torrents/televisionshowS01E01/.rar
No such file or directory
No files to extract
```

However, find /torrents/televisionshowS01*/ -name *.rar returns correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, looking at other people's bashscript I realized I should have backticks around the find command. Like so,

```
for i in `find /torrents/televisionshowS01*/ -name *.rar`; do unrar x "$i" /publicshare/; done
```

and then command functioned the way I wished it to. Though, I'm still not sure WHY, exactly. I'm assuming they work the way parentheses would in math. Obviously, it worked this time, but as a matter of good practice should I have put backticks around `unrar x "$i" /publicshare/`?

Thanks

Comment: Or you can leave out `find` entirely: `for i in /torrents/televisionshowS01*/*.rar; do …`